# Can I use two YOUTUBE APIs when using two different functionalities?

Tags: youtube-api

I am aware of the 1M quota for YT API. But is it legal to open two APIs, when they are created for different tasks. Lets say: First API get only the youtube videos statistics and the second is used for YT Player?

Answer (score 0):

It is all one api. But you can have as many hotkeys as you want. However to spread the quote, then you need more projects set up. But I think you are restricted to how many.

Comment: What means spread the quote? So i can have two times 1M tokens/day for two different tasks or just 1M tokens/day for all of the projects/purposes?

Comment: In Google console where you set up your projects, each project is what has the quota. So if you use more than one project in the same app/site , then you will have more quota. But you are limited to how many projects you can register for free. Read the info in your dashboard for full details.